# Blender unit conversion without scaling relative to the scene?

Tags: scale, units, conversion

I'm a fairly new employee and Blender user (long-time Maya user). I may have gotten myself into a bind and hoping you all can help me out...

As a new employee, one of the first things I asked was which unit we'd be using in Blender. I was told that everything is in centimeters unless specified otherwise, and that was rare. So I quickly set my units to centimeter, saved the startup file, and never looked back.

[image]

Well here we are a few months later and I'm learning that they don't really understand how units work in 3D software, so no one had ever changed anything from the default Blender Unit. All of our tools and exporters are written assuming that 1 BU = 1 cm. But after researching, it appears that 1 Blender Unit = 1 meter. I'm the first 3D artist that the company has hired, so it makes sense that they aren't very familiar with the software. No big deal, but now I have a problem...

I have rigged and animated a few scenes, which now need to be changed from centimeters to Blender Units. Unfortunately, a simple change in the units doesn't work, because then the scene is 100x too big.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to convert the units while maintaining the relative scale? The grid floor should appear the same size relative to the objects in the scene. Or maybe there is a way to scale the entire scene back down to the correct size, precisely and without screwing up the rigging/animation? This should be possible, as I don't have any animation on the armatures in object mode, only on individual joints in pose mode.

Thanks in advance for any tips or advice!!!

Comment: Have you tried selecting all and pressing S .01 ?

Comment: Yes, but scaling an animated rig and applying transforms, breaks the rig.

Answer (score 1):

I had exact the same problem - solution is - select whole scene, literaly everything and parent to empty, than scale empty :)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the grid by going to the tab settings on the right, scroll down until you hit *scale*, and size that up until you have a pleasing result.[image]